# c# - How can i re-size image resolution from 3000x2000 to 600 without losing image quality too much

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.forms, image-resizing

ImageCropper saves image resolution to 3000x2000 and image size to 6MB. This is a huge size for mobile app, I just need like resolution 600.

How can I re-size image without without losing image quality too much. is there plugin I can use?

on google, they seem to use stream to re-size which does work but here I don't have stream, just a path (string)

```
new ImageCropper()
{
    PageTitle = "Crop Photo",
    AspectRatioX = 4,
    AspectRatioY = 3, 
    CropShape = ImageCropper.CropShapeType.Rectangle,
    Success = (imagePath) =>
    {
        Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() =>
        {
            // here, plugin automatedly saves image in: cache folder but image is 3000x2000 and image size is 6MB
            // here, I already have image path (imagePath), so how can i use this path to re-size image
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: "I don't have stream, just a path" - [File.Open().](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.file.open?view=net-5.0).  There are dozens of existing questions about resizing images in Xamarin, and also dozens of existing questions about getting a file stream from a path.

Comment: thanks ill look into them now